# iOS App Export Compliance Information

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My app uses HTTPS and keychain as a credential storage.
I need some help with filling in the export compliance information form:

1. Does your app use encryption? (I answer **YES**)
2. Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations? (Well this is **the question**)

What should the answer to the second question be in case of just using keychain and HTTPS?

Comment: This may help you - https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15106/are-encryption-apps-ios-exempt-from-us-export-regulations-if-released-to-the-u

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].